# How to make custom cursor display over image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a portfolio site for myself and I made a custom cursor that follows the default one, by creating an empty div, styling it as a small circle, and making it trail behind the default cursor with Javascript. All of that works fine.

The problem is that once the cursor moves over an image, the circle is displaying under it.

HTML

```
<div class="cursor"></div>

<img src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/268338039154053677/D41BD0C4419DBF35C84CB17B2737B065504B1858/" alt="">
```

CSS

```
.cursor {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #0b0d0f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  console.log(e);
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: "+(e.pageY - 10)+"px; left: "+(e.pageX - 10)+"px;")
})
```

I would expect the custom cursor to hover over the image along with the default cursor, but instead is displays under it.

Comment: By "under" do you mean "lower on the page on the Y axis" or "behind and obscured by on the Z axis"? If the latter, have you tried setting either or both elements' [`z-index` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)?

Comment: I did mean obscured on the Z axis. Thanks, setting the z-index fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the hovering element a higher [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) in the CSS to make it appear in front of other elements ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hqsbpnt/)).

However, this may be a browser-specific problem—it works for me even without the z-index set.